# Arrays and linked List

Tags: arrays, linked-list

I want to know about arrays and linked list. which faster if you try to sort elements in arrays and linked list. which list index is faster array or linked list? and last thing if we try to find an element from array and linked list which will take less time to find the respective element?
i know little bit about arrays and linked list. correct me if I am wrong. arrays are fixed size and contiguous memory data structure. while linked list is not fixed size.

Comment: perhaps google will help you for this generic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SCJP certification book:

> ArrayList:
>
> Think of this as a growable array. It gives you fast iteration and fast
>   random access. To state the obvious: it is an ordered collection (by index), but not
>   sorted. You might want to know that as of version 1.4, ArrayList now implements
>   the new RandomAccess interface—a marker interface (meaning it has no methods)
>   that says, "this list supports fast (generally constant time) random access." **Choose
>   this  over a LinkedList when you need fast iteration but aren't as likely to be doing a
>   lot of insertion and deletion**
>
> LinkedList:
>
> A LinkedList is ordered by index position, like ArrayList, except
>   that the elements are doubly-linked to one another. This linkage gives you new
>   methods (beyond what you get from the List interface) for adding and removing
>   from the beginning or end, which makes it an easy choice for implementing a stack
>   or queue. Keep in mind that a LinkedList may iterate more slowly than an ArrayList,
>   but it's a good choice when you need fast insertion and deletion. As of Java 5, the 
>   LinkedList class has been enhanced to implement the java.util.Queue interface. As 
>   such, it now supports the common queue methods:
>   peek(), poll(), and offer()

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayList** is represented as an array, however the ArrayList class is doing everything, including resizing array, so you dont have to care about size.

```
Add to end : constant time
Add to else : linear time (average is n/2 = O(n))
Get : constant
Delete : same as add
```

**LinkedList** is represented as linked list. It means each part of linked list has access to the next part and before part.

```
Add to anywhere : constant time
Delete from anywhere : constant time
Get : linear time (average is n/2 = O(n))
```

But BOTH are lists, it means they are not fixed. The only difference is when you are using them, some methods are faster/slower than the others compare to another List implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are faster for all of these operations. The only time that linked lists are faster is when you need to delete or add an element. But for a fixed collection of items, arrays are always faster.